# How to remove part of a raster image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raster

I have the following icon as a raster image, and I need to extract the "i" to do something with it. I'm not able to identify the font (it isn't Times), so how might I go about "removing" the i from this so that I can manipulate it further? I tried Quick Select but it gets messy....

Is tracing it with the pen tool going to be my best bet?

[image]

Comment: Recreating might be the faster way. Plus you end up with a lossless file.

Comment: Since it is just one letter, I doubt that the world would come crashing down if you use another font that's somewhere around the ballpark... -- I bet bold Georgia would almost nail it. If you really want it to be identical, you could always convert that georgia i to a shape layer and make small corrections here and there and everywhere a moo, moo! That should be quite painless.

Answer (score 3):

The image is the standard "information icon" from Windows XP designed by The Iconfactory (iirc). The "i" is Georgia Bold, probably with 110% width and most likely tweaked on a per-pixel basis.

[image]

Comment: I don't think Mathew Carter came up with the 'i' for Georgia. That's the universal symbol for "information" used on maps, wayfinding systems, etc. It's been around a long time.

Comment: I meant to say that the image posted int he original questions was a greyscale close up of the windows xp stock icon. I may be wrong, but I never meant to suggest that iconfactory invented the "i" nor the typeface.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options:

1. Trace it with the pen tool(this is a faster option but it might not be exact{unless you are really good with pen tool} and you don't end up with a lossless file)
2. Do some research, find the font, and recreate it. ( Takes longer than option 1, but you end up with a completely lossless file that you can do anything you want with.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a similar font, you could do the following in Photoshop:

1. Grab the magic wand tool `W`.
2. Bring the `Tolerance` down to 15 or lower
3. Select the body of the "i"
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Mac) to duplicate that layer

The dot of the "i" would be easy

1. Grab the `Elliptical Marquee` tool
2. Move your mouse to the center of the dot
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> then click and drag to select a perfectly circular marque around the dot.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Mac) to duplicate that layer
5. Select both your newly created layers
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> for Mac) to Merge the layers

Done.